# Cast a Nokogiri::XML::Document to a Nokogiri::HTML::Document

Tags: ruby, casting, xml-serialization, html-parsing, nokogiri

I want to transform an XML document to HTML using XSL, tinker with it a little, then render it out. This is essentially what I'm doing:

```
source = Nokogiri::XML(File.read 'source.xml')
xsl = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read 'transform.xsl')
transformed = xsl.transform(source)
html = Nokogiri::HTML(transformed.to_html)
html.title = 'Something computed'
```

`Stylesheet::transform` always returns `XML::Document`, but I need a `HTML::Document` instance to use methods like `title=`.

The code above works, but exporting and re-parsing as HTML is just awful. Since the target is a subclass of the source, there must be a more effective way to perform the conversion.

How can I clean up this mess?

As a side question, Nokogiri has generally underwhelmed me with its handling of doctypes, unawareness of `<meta charset=` etc... does anyone know of a less auto-magic library with similar capabilities?

Many thanks ;)

Comment: Since `HTML::Document` is a subclass of `XML::Document` it doesn't look like there's a mechanism for converting. However, if you look at the HTML specific methods like `title` they're generally just selectors like `title = at('title') and title.inner_text`.  Not sure how many other HTML specific methods you need.

Comment: @GSP on balance, even this horrible form of casting is worthwhile for the HTML specific methods. I suspect having a HTML document instance is also more helpful for selectively representing null elements like `br` and `meta`. I did originally set the title using `css('head > title')` but I'm a firm believer that if someone's already written something well, you shouldn't write it again :)

Comment: There's really nothing special about `title` or any HTML helper like it in Nokogiri, that you can't safely replicate by yourself in the context of an XML document. Or, use `Nokogiri::Slop(doc_to_parse)` or `Nokogiri::XML(doc_to_parse).slop!` and let it do the work for you.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks, but the Slop decorator doesn't give me what I want from `HTML::Document`. Remember that HTML isn't XML—XHTML is, but HTML is based on SGML, which allows for tags like `<br>` vs `<br/>` in XHTML. Curiously, Nokogiri seems to respect these differences when transforming using XSLT with a `<xsl:output method="html"/>` element... ow, my head.

Comment: One more thought, since HTML::Document subclasses XML::Document can you simply start line one by using `Nokogiri::HTML(File.read 'source.xml')` even though it's not HTML at this point?

Comment: @GSP I'll give that a go. I suspect there will be issues with it wanting to treat non-namespaced elements like HTML even if they're not.. for example, `<br>some data</br>` might not turn out as expected pre-transformation. Still, worth a shot. I'll let you know how it goes . Ta :)

Comment: have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

`HTML::Document` extends `XML::Document`, but the individual nodes in a HTML document are just plain `XML::Nodes`, i.e. there aren’t any `HTML::Nodes`. This suggests a way of converting an XML document to HTML by creating a new empty `HTML::Document` and setting its `root` to that of the XML document:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.new
html.root= transformed.root
```

The new document has the HTML methods like `title=` and `meta_encoding=` available, and when serializing it creates a HTML document rather than HTML: adds a HTML doctype, correctly uses empty tags like `<br>`, displays minimized attributes where appropriate (e.g. `<input type="checkbox" selected>`) and doesn’t escape things like `>` in `<script>` blocks.